# How to send http request to mocked controller using MockMvc?

Tags: java, spring, testing, spring-mvc, mocking

I have this class for test. This test uses mockMvc object. My opinion that this object send http requests and these requests handles controller which configuration takes from `pathToFile.xml`

```
    @ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/pathToFile.xml" })
    @WebAppConfiguration
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    public class CandidateControllerTest {
        @Autowired
        WebApplicationContext wac;

        MockMvc mockMvc;

        @Before
        public void before() {
           mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webApplicationContextSetup(wac).build();

        }
...
}
```

I think that sometimes I want use controller with other configuration.

What does it mean?

`CandidateControllerTest` tests methods of `CandidateController` class

```
@Controller
CandidateController{

   @Autowire
   CandidateService candidateService;

   @RequestMapping("/path")
   public string handleSomething(Model model){
    ...
      candidateService.doSomething();
    ...
      return "viewName"

   }

}
```

I want to mock  `candidateService`  an sent http requests to controller with mocked `candidateService`

It is really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a setter for the `candidateService` in your `CandidateController` class.

In your `CandidateControllerTest`, get the `CandidateController` bean from the `WebApplicationContext` and use the setter to set the mock.

```
CandidateService candidateServiceMock = ...; // mock it
CandidateController cc = (CandidateController) wac.getBean(CandidateController.class);
cc.setCandidateService(candidateServiceMock);
```

---

I don't recommend this. If you were simply testing the `CandidateController` **on its own**, this would be fine. But you are testing it behind the `MockMvc`, which is integration testing. A mock doesn't belong in the stack being tested.

Comment: CandidateService will reset after every test?

Comment: @homeAccount You can choose whether you want to or not. With mocks I would probably reset it after every test.

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis, It is realy make similar trick for Model, RedirecAttributes and ModelAttributes (spring productions) ?